# Is it possible to add particlejs in opencart using text editor or any other way?

Tags: opencart, opencart-3

Instead of banner, I am trying to add particle js in home banner section  using html content editor. But i'm struggling on particle js code.

Any help

Comment: which `code` are you not able to add from the `content editor`?

Comment: i want to use js code for particlejs in opencart

Comment: you need to add the JS Code directly into the `template` file, that won't work in the `HTML Content Editor`. Rest `HTML` code you can add in the content editor.